# Javascript - Removing commas from an array of string numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently have an array of strings that are numbers

```
data.dataArr = [0: " 1,431,417 "
​​
1: " 1,838,127 "
​​
2: " 679,974 "
​​
3: " 2,720,560 "
​​
4: " 544,368 "
​​
5: " 1,540,370 "]
```

I am attempting to remove the commas so my data returns `0: "1431417" , 1: 1838127 ...`

After removing commas I am then mapping this array to convert it to an array of numbers and not strings. But when console.logging the finalArray that should return an array of numbers I am getting `NaN` I believe this is due to the part of removing the commas.

Here is my code:

```js
let data = {
  dataArr: [
  " 1,431,417 ",
    " 1,838,127 ",
    " 679,974 ",
    " 2,720,560 ",
    " 544,368 ",
    " 1,540,370 "
  ]
};

//removing commas
let arrData = data.dataArr.map(e => e.replace(/(,\s*)+/, ','));
let finalArr = arrData.map(Number);
console.log(finalArr)
```

alternatively I've tried :

`let arrData = data.dataArr.replace(/,/g, "")`

Which resulted in `"data.dataArr.replace is not a function"`

Comment: You're using invalid data. Arrays are not key:value pairs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use number in same `map` callback function, `g` to remove all occurrence of `,`

```js
dataArr = [" 1,431,417 ", " 1,838,127 ", " 679,974 ", " 2,720,560 ", " 544,368 ", " 1,540,370 "]

let arrData = dataArr.map(e => Number(e.replace(/(,\s*)+/g, '').trim()));
console.log(arrData)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
      ['1,234', '7,8,90,'].map(eachNo => {
return eachNo.split(',').join('')
});
```

> **Split()** will split string where it will find ,(comma) and will return
>   an array of strings.
>   **join()** will operate on array of strings.

Answer (score 2):

There also seems to be a space in your array which would be giving NaN, Remove everything other than digits and maybe a dot.

Try this regex:

```
e.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
```

Comment: `\D` is the same as `[^\d]`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const data = {};
data.dataArr = [
  "   1,431,417 ",
  " 1,838,127 ",
  " 679,974 ",
  " 2,720,560 ",
  " 544,368 ",
  " 1,540,370 ",
];

const numbersArray = data.dataArr.map(str => Number(str.replace(/\D/g, '')));

console.log(numbersArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```js
var data = {};

data.dataArr =
  [
    " 1,431,417 ",
    " 1,838,127 ",
    " 679,974 ",
    " 2,720,560 ",
    " 544,368 ",
    " 1,540,370 "
  ];

function array_to_numbers(_arr){
 var out = [];
 for(var key in _arr){
   var el =  _arr[key];
   el = el.trim();
   el = el.replace(new RegExp(',','g'), '');
   el = parseInt(el)||0;
   out.push(el);
 }
 return out;
}
console.log(array_to_numbers(data.dataArr));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `.map()` over the array and split up by `,` and then join them at `""`. You also need to wrap everything in `Number` to convert it to an number

```js
let dataArr =  [
  " 1,431,417 ",
    " 1,838,127 ",
    " 679,974 ",
    " 2,720,560 ",
    " 544,368 ",
    " 1,540,370 "
  ]
  
  let result = dataArr.map(el => Number(el.split(",").join("")))
  
  console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = new Object();
data.dataArr = [ " 1,431,417 ",
" 1,838,127 ",
" 679,974 ",
" 2,720,560 ",
" 544,368 ",
" 1,540,370 "];

const finalArr = data.dataArr.map(x => x.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));

console.log(finalArr)
```

Comment: The regex here `/[^0-9]/g` should actually be replaced with `/[^+-0-9.]/g` as otherwise negative and decimal numbers will be corrupted